# Adding buttons with touchBegan

Tags: swift, button, sprite-kit, xcode7, touchesbegan

I playing around with a Swift game from GitHub.  I am attempting to add another button to the touchesBegan (newButton).  Here is what I got so far:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard !gameOver else {
        let gameOverLayer = childNodeWithName(StickHeroGameSceneChildName.GameOverLayerName.rawValue) as SKNode?
        let location = touches.first?.locationInNode(gameOverLayer!)
        let retry = gameOverLayer!.nodeAtPoint(location!)
        if (retry.name == StickHeroGameSceneChildName.RetryButtonName.rawValue) { 
            print("Retry")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("hideBanner", object: nil)
            retry.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "button_retry_down"), resize: false), SKAction.waitForDuration(0.3)]), completion: {[unowned self] () -> Void in
                self.restart()
            })   
        }
        return
    }
    guard !gameOver else {
        let gameOverLayer2 = childNodeWithName(StickHeroGameSceneChildName.GameOverLayerName.rawValue) as SKNode?
        let location2 = touches.first?.locationInNode(gameOverLayer2!)
        let games = gameOverLayer2!.nodeAtPoint(location2!)
        if (newButton.name == StickHeroGameSceneChildName.GamesButtonName.rawValue) { 
            print("New Button")
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Here is the code for the buttons:

```
let retry = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button_retry_up")
retry.name = StickHeroGameSceneChildName.RetryButtonName.rawValue
retry.position = CGPointMake(0, -180)
node.addChild(retry)

let newButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button_games_up")
newButton.name = StickHeroGameSceneChildName.GamesButtonName.rawValue
newButton.position = CGPointMake(0, -360)
node.addChild(newButton)
```

There is the GitHub:  https://github.com/phpmaple/Stick-Hero-Swift
I'm pretty new at Swift and need a little guidance.  Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @Untitled123 Sorry. I am trying to add another button (newButton).

Comment: Looks like you've added it. Whats the question? I really suggest learning what you're copy/pasting. Your code is slightly nonsense. You only need the one `guard` statement, in there you can check the name of the touched node. I would suggest learning line by line what the first guard statement is doing (I'm guessing that's from the github link?). If you truly understand that, you'll be on much more solid ground.

Comment: The first `guard` already gets the location of the first touch, in the `gameOverLayer`. You don't need to make another guard statement and do that again. `retry` is the name of the touched node at that point. You can test against that node's name to see which node was touched. That's what the `if` statement does.